# In C, is there a way to calculate the size of allocated memory filled with null-terminators?

Tags: arrays, c, string, strlen

I need something like `strlen` but the string is filled with only null-terminators `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"` and I need to fill it with another character up until (not including) the last `\0` like so `"FFFFFF\0"`. Is there a way to calculate the size without errors?

I had to implement `bzero` for a school project called "libft". Then I was tasked with implementing `strcpy` and I saw in the man pages that `dest` needs to be large enough to receive the copy of `src` so I want to account for a situation where `bzero` was used on `dest` and `strcpy` doesn't allow me to pass the size of `dest` as a parameter. I was just wondering (out of curiosity) how I would know how big `dest` is because I know that `strcpy` does not account for this. There is a warning in the man page "Beware of buffer overruns! (See BUGS.)".

I realise now that this might be impossible in C.

Comment: That area of memory had to be allocated some way. If you have a 'string' filled with nuls it is no longer a string.

Comment: @dawg Yes, I know it's no longer a string that's why I double-quoted it. I don't know what it's called if not just allocated memory.

Comment: Keep track of how that area was allocated and there is your answer. If you you don't know what was allocated, it it was not allocated, then that will be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking is whether you can know how much memory has been allocated.

If it was allocated with `malloc`, no.

If it's an array allocated on the stack, like `char foo[10]`, yes you can use `sizeof(foo)`, but that doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know.

If you need to know the allocated size of the string, you need to remember it at allocation time and pass it around. You can use an extra variable, or you can make a `struct` which has both the string and size.

Comment: Not that its a good idea but ```malloc``` tracks size so if you want to write absolutely non portable code that is liable to break every time you switch libraries you could go into the ```malloc``` internals. For glibc ```malloc``` for large blocks size is stored in 8 bytes preceding returned ptr in memory.

Comment: @Noah For glibc there is no need for that - there is `malloc_usable_size`.

Comment: That should probably be in the answer then for glibc malloc at least

Comment: @Noah That's good info, but I'm not familiar with compiler-specific features. Write it up as its own answer.

Comment: @Noah I've used that trick before. But, it gives the _usable_ size (and _not_ specific allocated size). That is: `malloc(9)` and `malloc(10)` will _both_ yield: `16 | ptr` because the hidden size is aligned [upward] "for any usage" (i.e. `8`, `sizeof(double)`, `sizeof(void *)`, etc.). So, from 16, one can't deduce whether the call was 9 or 10. Also, heap routines could make the alignment _anything_ (e.g. 64). And, the alignment amount _could_ be done on a "per arena" basis.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no generic way. If your `char * input` fulfils `*input == '\0'`, then it is a null terminated string of size zero, and we cannot know whether `input[n]` is valid for *any* `n > 0`.

However, if you had control over the allocation of `input` or any other hint, you can use *that* information, e.g.

```
input = malloc(N);
/* use N */
```

Otherwise, it's completely opaque.